# Is it possible to edit DIV tag id name using functions?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a plugin that uses 3 completely identical divs on the page, using the same classes.

`<div class="my-class">
<div class="my-class">
<div class="my-class">`

I would like to edit the code of the plugin and add an `id` to each div, so I can work with it
later using css.

But I don't want to touch the parent code due to the later update issues.

Is there a way to add the id tag to a div using just functions placed in functions.php file ??

---

Guys, also 1 additional question following the 1 above.

You have downvoted this question -2. I have recently received a message from administrator about my account restriction due to this. 
I don't think I asked a stupid question and I'm not a coder my self so maybe it was stupid, but obviously I'm just trying to understand why you didn't take it very well and what type of questions should I avoid in the future.
Your comment would be really appreciated, specially the one who gave it a downvote. Cheers.

Comment: What is `functions.php`?

Comment: id is unique you should be using classes well...

Comment: What is your exact requirement

Comment: @JamesDonnelly you might be on the wrong forums :)

Comment: @BhojendraSah - well spotted, id is unique, that is why i want to use id because the current classes are all identical.

Comment: @KirenSiva - I am asking if there is any way to use actions and filters to add an `id` to a div tag. So each wordpress installation has a functions.php file or similar, is there a filter that would add an `id` to a `div` tag ??

Comment: @JoeBloggs nope: "using just functions placed in functions.php file"

Comment: That answers my question James, thanks, will go as @panther suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can differ them using CSS, without need to add them ID attribute.

```
<div class="my-class"></div>
<div class="my-class"></div>
<div class="my-class"></div>

<style>
    .my-class {width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red;} /* rules for all .my-class elements, eg. width&height, whatever */
    .my-class:nth-child(2) {background: green}
    .my-class:nth-child(3) {background: blue}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwy38om7/

Comment: I know I can use `:nth-child()` in my css ( and it works ), but is there a way this could be done using filters and actions ?

Comment: @JoeBloggs: Without knowledge of `functions.php` nobody can help you more. It'd be probably possible using conditions, but you showed us only a few codes of HTML, and it's all we're able to help you with (based on your question).

Comment: That's all I have, sorry, I have 3 divs literally stuck on each other, all with the exact same class. I know that I can either hack the code directly or I could use your solution using css, but I was thinking maybe I could use a function or some kind of a filter using the functions.php file and assign them an id this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer them using Jquery like

```
$(".my-class").each(function() {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below javascript to add id to your div

```
i=0;
$(".my-class").each(function() {
$(this).attr('id', 'constanttext' + i);
i++;
})
```

Comment: The `i` variable is pretty redundant. `each` passes a element reference and a sequential index parameter